# how to get public key from certificate on azure automation

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, ssl, ssh

I need to get SSH public key from the certificate which is store on azure portal and I have created workflow on azure automation and import the certificate to azure portal. Once we get the SSH public key, I have to create linux VM with this SSH public key(Ready this script from myend without add SSH key).

Comment: what type of certificate? PEM? X.509? openSSH?

Comment: X.509 which is generate using makecert.exe

Comment: So you need PowerShell script on this?

Comment: @juvchan yes, required powershell script code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, your certificate should be DER encoded X.509 certificate with **.cer** extension.

You can get the public key from your certificate using the PowerShell script below:

```
$certPath = "testcert.cer"
$x509Cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile($certPath)
$pk = $x509Cert.GetPublicKeyString()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing code but Certificate is store on azure portal and if I execute this code on azure automation(workflow) then getting below error: *exception
Exception calling "CreateFromCertFile" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path." (Illegal characters in path.)*

Comment: So what certificate store on Azure do you want to retrieve? Management certificate? Please be more specific so it's useful for analysis and reproducing

Comment: Two way to add ssh key 1) Retrieve the key from management certificate on azure portal using azure automation (OR) 2) Store the plain SSH key on variable and using this create linux vm (I don't want to add ssh public PATH on script) . If you have any solution for above options.